# Is Batman's suit in Batman Beyond bulletproof?

Tags: dc, batman, batman-beyond

Is the high-tech bat-suit of **Batman Beyond** bulletproof and armored against small arms and energy-based weapons (e.g. "Laser guns")?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-Terry-McGinnis-hi-tech-Batsuit-bulletproof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has proven its worth against small arms, up to and including Terry being shot in the head and sustained minigun fire.

[image: Terry tanking a shot from Vigilante] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Terry taking a shot to the head] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Terry providing cover for civilians against an assault rifle] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

[image: Terry taking fire from the Joker Borg's minigun] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

I don't have an image for lasers yet, but [the Fandom wiki](https://dccomicsfannon.fandom.com/wiki/Batsuit_Beyond) notes "The Suit was very durable, being able to withstand massive concussive forces, fire, water, lasers, and electric shocks."

Comment: There's a collection of the amount of times he got zapped in the animated series there: https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Terry_McGinnis%27_Batsuit#Paraphernalia In the section _"Significant resistance to water, electricity, heat and radiation"_

Comment: Same link has a section for "Enhanced ballistic protection". I think I'm going to update my answer

Comment: This answer would be significantly better with issue numbers for each image. It'd make it easier for people viewing those images to track down and read the full issues if they want, and/or verify which specific continuity the stories are set in. It may be the case that the Batman Beyond Batsuit is more bullet/laserproof in some continuities than others.

Comment: I will look at adding those when I get home from work tonight.

Answer (score 6):

The [Batman Beyond's suit](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Terry_McGinnis%27_Batsuit#Paraphernalia) gives its wearer many advantages, one of which is its increased durability, allowing Terry to withstand damages that would be deadly to a regular human-being, such as walking through flames, getting zapped, and getting shot at.

In the DC Animated Universe, there are a few scenes during which he got shot; mostly in [Batman Beyond (1999)](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Beyond) animated series.

In episode *[Blood Sport](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Bloodsport_(episode))* from *Batman Beyond*, Terry got pushed into a trap led for him, in which a bunch of devices were shooting darts at high speed towards him. Beside the fact it was painful, he did not seem to have sustained any serious damage:

In episode *[Eyewitness](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Eyewitness)* from *Batman Beyond*, Terry was framed for the (supposedly) murder of one of the villains from his rogue gallery, because of which Barbara ordered the entire Gotham Police Department to arrest him. In the pursuit, he got shot down by a helicopter and survived it:

In episode *[Out of the Past](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Out_of_the_Past)* from *Batman Beyond*, Terry got shot by Talia (but with Ra's Al Ghul's mind) with a laser/energy pistol. He survived the ordeal even if he got hurt:

In episode [The Once and Future Thing Part Two: Time, Warped](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/The_Once_and_Future_Thing_Part_Two:_Time,_Warped) from the *[Justice League Unlimited (2004)](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited_(animated_series))* animated series, Terry (with the Batman Beyond batsuit) got shot by 3 [Redcoats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_coat_(military_uniform)) who got transported into the future because of a time shift.

The shots are not fatale, although he seemed to have been severely hurt because of it, because he no longer had the strength to escape from his restraint later on, which resulted in him getting killed:

Some other notables examples for which I wasn't able to find a video on Youtube:

- In episode *[Ascension](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Ascension)* from *Batman Beyond*, he got betrayed after helping [Derek Power (aka. Blight)](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Derek_Powers)'s son in capturing him. One of the henchmen shot him and he survived the ordeal.
- In episode *[Lost Soul](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Lost_Soul)* from *Batman Beyond*, he got hit by a laser blast as he was trying to disable the system that went haywire, although it's arguable whether or not that shot was intended to be fatale. In that episode, Terry's suit was possessed by an AI, and leading him into this trap was all part of the plan to possess it.
- In episode *[Sentries of the Last Cosmos](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Sentries_of_the_Last_Cosmos)* from *Batman Beyond*, he was hit by a surprise shot from the shadow while he was investigating. This didn't stop him from fighting back and disarming the unknown assailant with a batarang.